# First Steps IONIC - Difficulty Login

Tags: url, authentication, ionic-framework, forms-authentication

I needed a lot of your help to begin to better understand how to work with IONIC.
I have a simple login screen, I need to do an authentication via an external URL. For example my URL is: **http://213.58.146.179/App/GetUser**.
When making a GET URL returns me a json file:

```
{"Successfull":true,"SuccessMessage":"","ErrorNumber":0,"ErrorMessage":"","Action":"","ReturnObject":[{
    " User " : {
        " ID " : 3,
        " IntegrationID " : null,
        " UserName " : "admin",
        " Name " : " Trivalor Admin ",
        " Email " : " example@demo.com ",
        " Phone " : null,
        " Mobile " : null,
        " Locale " : " pt_PT ",
        " Active " : true,
        " LastLogin " : " 2016-06-21T22:18:02.2",
        " PasswordDate " : "2016-04-26T09:09:45.683",
        " PasswordExpired " : false,
        " isExternal " : null,
        " ExternalUser " : null,
        " LocationsIDs " : null
    },
    }]
```

Please with this information how can I build the authentication of my app?

After being authenticated, I'll get a list of data to display on the screen.
I would appreciate very give me a few steps, or good practices to apply in this case.
I am newbie in the world of programming.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple actually. Just get the url through ajax in the loginController and if the response is true, redirect to the authenticated page. Then you can make the authentication logic shift to token based and have the different complex logic into it.

```
$http.get("http://213.58.146.179/App/GetUser").then(function(response){
   if(response.Successfull == true){
       $state.go('yourStateName'); 
    }
  }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("http error", data);
  });
```